# Is it possible to plot logistic regression with categorical variables as independent variables?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have tried both r plot and ggplot. They don't allow plotting logistic regression curve when you have categorical variables as independent variables (x-axis). When I tried after converting the categorical variables to random numbers, it worked. But that's confusing. Is there any solution, or am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

For example:

```r
g <- ggplot(decision_use, aes(x=decision, y=use)) + geom_point(alpha=.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", 
    method.args = list(family = "binomial"), 
    se = FALSE)
```

and

```r
plot(decision, use)
g=glm(use~decision,family=binomial, decision_use)
curve(predict(g,data.frame(decision=x),type="resp"),add=TRUE)
```

With decision as types of people and use as 1 or 0.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @mcskinner Posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this package that gives you great effects plots.

Let LogitModel be your Logistic Regression model

```
install.packages("effects") # only need to do once. 
library(effects)
plot(allEffects(LogitModel))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great set of examples [https://data.library.virginia.edu/visualizing-the-effects-of-logistic-regression](https://data.library.virginia.edu/visualizing-the-effects-of-logistic-regression/)/  It doesn't use ggplot but has an example of effect of a categorical variable among the examples.

One with ggplot https://blogs.uoregon.edu/rclub/2016/04/05/plotting-your-logistic-regression-models/

Comment: Thank you. The UVA link deals with multiple data frames and glm for all. I have two data frames, one with 1 or 0 and the other with types. I want probability for each type. Would you know an answer for my case?

Comment: I would merge them together.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again, and the UVA example relies on using effects library. I followed it, and the outcome isn't a logistic curve but rather a straight, horizontal curve that doesn't reflect the data. Is there a way to plot a logistical regression curve for categorical variables as independent variables? ggplot or given r plot.